# Why "|| true" and >/dev/null expressions are so often used in logrotate postrotate configuration?

Tags: logrotate

There are coutless examples of logrotate configs which contain the following:

```
postrotate
  systemctl reload nginx 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null || true
endscript
```

but what is the motivation behind it? Why is this so overwhelmingly common? Isn't it sane to deliver the output to some files/logs to be able to easily debug if something goes wrong etc?

Comment: Because people are stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case errors of the reloading of service can be ignored in the logrotate because them will be processed by the systemd itself, when the reload command will be executed.

Also, the log messages will be stored in the journal anyway so to avoid of duplication the additional output is ignored.

Comment: but will these journal entries include the information that the particular systemctl call was issued by a particular logrotate configuration entry?

Comment: Not. But I think it doesn't matter because this problem caused by something else, not reload command itself.

Comment: but what if someone mistakengly writes for example "systeCMtl reload nginx 2> /dev/null" ? will the issue pop up in journal?)